# Send vlc images to the HDMI port on Pi 4

Tags: hdmi, video, headless

Attach a keyboard and mouse to Pi 4, log in, interface is through HDMI port. Invoke vlc on a jpeg, image also goes to the HDMI port. I want the same to happen headless. That is log in remotely via ssh, invoke vlc, I want the image to go out the HDMI port.

Comment: why do you want to send an image to a non-existent display?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has asked a question that is unclear or confusing. OP has asked about running `vlc` on a *"headless"* (a.k.a. `Lite`) system. This may show a lack of research before asking the question.

Comment: I have a cable plugged into the HDMI port and a TV on the other end of the cable. Sorry if I was not clear. I want to display images processed by vlc to whatever is attached to the HDMI port. It mus be possible because it happens when there is a keyboard and mouse plugged into the Pi.

Comment: I wouldn’t typically consider a computer with a display and without a keyboard/mouse headless. I would reserve that for when there is no display, mouse, and keyboard. Are you asking for how you can automate displaying images (through VLC) via SSH?